# ERROR: could not find function "createRenderFunction"

Tags: menuitem, shinydashboard

**Dynamic content**

http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#dynamic-content

*A sidebar menu can be generated dynamically, with renderMenu and sidebarMenuOutput. Here is an example app with a sidebar that is generated on the server side.*

I was trying to implement the example from the link above but gives me the error-

***Warning: Error in createRenderFunction: could not find function "createRenderFunction"***

Is there an update to the package I missed?

```
    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
      ),
      dashboardBody()
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {
      output$menu <- renderMenu({
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Menu item", icon = icon("calendar"))
        )
      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that my Shiny package was at version 1.0.5, however 'createRenderFunction' is in version 1.1.0. So, updated the package and voila!